# Error trying to upload a video and its image

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a video and its image to my database. But it doesn't work. `$error` variable's content doesn't even appear.
I have this error:  `Notice: getimagesize(): Read error!`

I'm not able to fix it... Can you help me?

That's the function that I call in the HTML file, before the form tag (to print there the div that has the `$error` variable's content)

PHP

```
    public static function SubirVideo($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, $user, $descripcion){
        //ID AUTO INCREMENT
        $sql = "INSERT INTO video(nombre, directorio, imagen, visitas, likes, usuario_id, fecha_subida, descripcion) VALUES ($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, 0, 0, $user, NOW(), $descripcion)";
        $resultado = self::Conexion($sql);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public static function SubirVideoErrores(){
        $error = "";

        if(isset($_POST["boton_upload_video"])){
            $titulo = $_POST["video_title"];
            $descripcion = $_POST["video_description"];

            $uploadImagen = $_FILES['video_imagen']['name'];
            $tipoImagen = $_FILES['video_imagen']['type'];

            $uploadVideo = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
            $tipoVideo = $_FILES['video_file']['type'];

            if(!empty($uploadVideo) && !empty($uploadImagen)){
                $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tapeHD/include/database/usuarios/".$_SESSION["usuario"]."/videos";

                if($tipoImagen != "image/jpeg"){
                    $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen debe ser de formato .jpg</div></div></div>";
                    print $error;
                } else {
                    $file_tmp = $_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name'];
                    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

                    if($_FILES['video_imagen']['size'] > (1024000)){
                        $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen pesa demasiado</div></div></div>";
                        print $error;
                    } else {
                        if($width == 320 || $height == 180){
                            if($tipoVideo == "video/mp4"){
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'], $directorio."/".$uploadVideo);
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name'], $directorio."/".$uploadImagen);
                                $video_directorio = "include/database/usuarios/".$_SESSION["usuario"]."/videos/".$uploadFile;
                                $imagen_directorio = "include/database/usuarios/".$_SESSION["usuario"]."/videos/".$uploadImagen;
                                DataBase::SubirVideo($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, $_SESSION["usuario"], $descripcion);
                                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>Tu video ha sido subido</div></div></div>";
                                print $error;
                            } else {
                                $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>El video debe estar en formato .mp4</div></div></div>";
                                print $error;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $error = "<div id='error_alert'><div class='error_container'><i class='fa fa-times awesome error_close btn'></i><div class='error_text'>La imagen debe de ser 320x180</div></div></div>";
                            print $error;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Double check that the file is there and valid. I would also suggest you to change your code so it won't have so many sub-blocks. For example, instead of if (ALL_OK) {.. } else { showError } do if (!ALL_OK) { showError; return} .... This way the code would be much more readable.

Comment: I updated in the way you said. Check it out now...

Comment: Antonio, the code readability is not the real problem here, it's just a tip. And the idea is to `return` after printing so no `else` and new block is needed, therefore no indentation. Back to the original issue: Have you double checked that the file at `$_FILES['video_imagen']['tmp_name']` is valid and has valid image data?

Comment: How can I do it? I don't understand you really well